# Como crear una tabla de forma dinamica desde el resultado listado de una consulta en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-procedimiento

Tengo que generar un reporte y se me ocurrio lo mas rapido para encolumnar e insertar de forma dinamica valores de calificaciones por cada materia.
Mi tabla de materias tiene idmateria, descripcion y mi objetivo era una tabla con los id de los inscriptos y cada materia que tenga su convocatoria, cosa que no podria meter manualmente ya que algunas convocatorias tienen mas materias que otras.

ej1: idinscripcion,matematica, ciencias
ej2: idinscripcion,matematica, ciencias,historia,fisica

Por lo que pude crear unos procedimientos en mysql

````
#CALL crear_tabla(@a);
#drop procedure crear_tabla;
#select * from tmp_reporte_gral;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE crear_tabla(out res int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE vdescripcion varchar(200);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE resultado CURSOR FOR SELECT descripcion FROM materia;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    
    drop table if exists `tmp_reporte_gral`;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp_reporte_gral` (
    `idinscripcion` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idinscripcion`));
OPEN resultado;
      read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH resultado INTO vdescripcion;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        CALL alteracion_tabla(vdescripcion,@a);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE resultado;
END$$



#CALL alteracion_tabla('hola1',@a);
#drop procedure alteracion_tabla;
#select * from tmp_reporte_gral;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE alteracion_tabla(vcolumna varchar(100),out res int)
BEGIN
    SET @myquery = concat('ALTER TABLE tmp_reporte_gral ADD ',vcolumna,' VARCHAR(100) NULL;') ;
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @myquery;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
END$$
DELIMITER ;```
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual es el problema?